# Why do backticks not work in the SET part of an UPDATE query (for MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The following SQL

```
UPDATE line_items SET `line_items.quantity` = 2 where line_items.id = 1234;
```

gives me this error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'line_items.quantity' in 'field list'
```

However, these queries all work as expected:

```
UPDATE line_items SET line_items.quantity = 2 where line_items.id = 1234;
UPDATE line_items SET `quantity` = 2 where line_items.id = 1234;
UPDATE line_items SET quantity = 2 where line_items.id = 1234;
```

Any reason why backticks would not work in this specific case?

My current MySQL version is `Server version: 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)` which I installed last week. I haven't tried other versions.

The reason I ask is I have a more complicated UPDATE+JOIN query that Ruby on Rails is generating which does not work because Rails adds the backticks. I'm trying to figure out who's at fault: Rails, MySQL, or me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include in the backticking the period separator between table name and column name.  When you do this it sees the entire thing as a column name.

You want this:

```
`line_items`.`quantity`
```

NOT

```
`line_items.quantity`
```

The final query should look like:

```
 UPDATE line_items SET `line_items`.`quantity` = 2 where line_items.id = 1234;
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I missed that. By the way, I found a way to get Rails to generate the query without the backticks: I changed `.update_all('line_items.quantity' => 2)` to `.update_all(['line_items.quantity = ?', 2])`.